# Tensorflow: How to build a matrix from a dictionary of vectors?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, tensorflow, concatenation

I'd like to do something in tensorflow that is pretty easy in NumPy. I can't figure out how to do it in tf and I also have some doubts about whether it'd work as I mean to.

Basically in NumPy, I'd have a dictionary of randomly initialised column vectors.
Something like

```
F = 6
keys = np.arange(1.0,4.0)
init_dict = {}
for key in keys:
    init_dict[key] = np.random.random(size=(F,1))
```

I have a row vector containing a certain number of keys, so I build a matrix where each column is one of the column vectors contained in the dict.
It looks something like this

```
inp = np.hstack((keys,keys)).reshape(1,-1)
mat = np.repeat(inp, F, axis=0)
for i in range(mat.shape[1]):
    mat[:,i] = init_dict[mat[0,i]][:,0]
```

This `mat` then goes into my model.
The idea would be to train the randomly initialised column vectors that are stored in `init_dict`.

I'd like to do the same in TF.
How to build something similar to `mat` in TF?

Basically `mat` would be a `tf.Variable` where each column refers to another `tf.Variable` (the one in the dict)...this is a bit obscure to me, especially in terms of backprop, as I want all the gradients for columns of `mat` that are the same to contribute to the corresponding vector stored in the dict.

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`tf.stack`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stack). Example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

session = tf.InteractiveSession()

d = {
  'foo': tf.Variable([1, 2, 3]),
  'bar': tf.Variable([4, 5, 6]),
  'baz': tf.Variable([7, 8, 9]),
}

session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
print(d['foo'].eval())
# >>> [1 2 3]

mat = tf.stack(list(d.values()), axis=1)
print(mat.eval())
# >>> [[1 4 7]
#      [2 5 8]
#      [3 6 9]]
```